Is it possible to update the view after a model attribute change?
In a view that I have modified a lot, I notice that the date format of the Datepickers is not adapted to what I want.

I do not want hours. After research, I discover that it is advisable to add an attribute to the DateTime properties of the model:
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]

I then assume that this attribute addition should be applied to the view. But I do not know how to do it.
Can we reload a view so that it takes into account the changes, or should we delete it and build a new one?

May I know which .net version you are working on? And about your question "update the view after a model attribute change" -> do you mean you want to change the view by modifying the DisplayFormat attribute and you want to make the change take effect without restart the application?

Please allow me to share my test within .Net 8 MVC APP and I think this might be of benefit to show the result. Below is my code, and just like what you can see, I have different date format setting on the model, and I have type="date" configuration on one of the input.
<div>
    <label asp-for="MyDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="MyDate" type="date" class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="MyDate2" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, new { @type = "date" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate2, new { })
</div>

public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime MyDate2 { get; set; }
}


Just like what you can see in the screenshot, [DisplayFormat] makes the value in DOM has different behavior, but it doesn't affect the appearence in UI, it's type="date" makes the date input to only display date without time. In the meantime, the [DisplayFormat] attribution requires an application restart to take effect.

Thanks,
That's a solution, and it works for me. It was primarily a display issue that was causing a problem.

Thanks a lot for your update and confirmation : )
